# How to handle unauthorized Django Rest API calls

Tags: django, rest, authentication

I have a difficulty to understand how to connect my Angular front-end with the Django Rest API backend.

In the front-end I like to get read-only data from the API nonetheless the user is logged in or not.

Both front-end and back-end run on the same server and Django Rest has:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

Do I have to authenticate the front-end app to the API?
If so how do I keep my credentials secure?
Or do I have to mark certain endpoints as unauthorized read only?

Comment: You have to specify the permission classes and authentication classes on your views. For read-only, you can use from `permissions` in `rest_framework` - `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`. Please, post any view for an example.

Comment: Aha like those decorators? I was using viewsets, but I guess I have to split them up to make it read only

Comment: In class based viewsets, you can use `permission_classes=(class_name, )` and similarly, for `authentication_classes`. Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: So to conclude, it is normal that the front-end has to authenticate itself to the API unless you open up views as read only?

Comment: If this is the default behaviour for all the views (leaving aside one or two), you can also setup Django settings so that default permission and authentication classes are what you want for most of the views. Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy

Comment: I just realized that opening up the whole API for only the front-end IP address is very insecure. Since everyone can messing around with the ajax calls